# How to resolve a global variable in a module?

Tags: python, module, python-2.7, global-variables

I have a script as follows

```
from mapper import Mapper

class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print "world"

a = A()
a.foo()
Mapper['test']()
```

with `Mapper` defined in the file `mapper.py`:

```
Mapper = {'test': a.foo}
```

where I want to define a function call referencing an object not defined in `mapper.py`, but in the original code. However the code above gives the error

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

which makes kind of sense, as `a` is not defined in `mapper.py` itself. However, is it possible to change the code to let the code do the name resolution in the main code itself, or by the use of `globals` or something?

To solve this problem I could specify the implementation in `mapper.py` as a text and use `eval` in the main code, but I would like to avoid the usage of `eval`.

Additional information:

- The full definition of the function has to be made in `mapper.py`
- It is not known beforehand what the instance `a` is, or from what clas it is instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring security holes like `eval`, it's not possible to use a name `a` in `mapper.py` unless the name is either defined somewhere in `mapper.py` or imported from another module.  There is no way to just let `mapper.py` automatically and silently access a value `a` from a different module.

In addition, if you're using it just in a dict as in your example, `a.foo` is going to be evaluated as soon as the dict is created.  It's not going wait until you actually call the function; as soon as it evaluates `a.foo` to create the dict, it will fail because it doesn't know what `a` is.

You could get around this second problem by wrapping the element in a function (using a lambda for brevity):

```
Mapper = {'test': lambda: a.foo}
```

. . . but this still won't help unless you can somehow get `a` to be available inside `mapper.py`.

One possibility is to parameterize your `Mapper` by the "mystery" object and then pass that object in from outside:

```
# mapper.py
Mapper = {'test': lambda a: a.foo}

# other module
from mapper import Mapper
Mapper['test'](a)()
```

Or, similar to what `mgilson` suggested, you could "register" the object `a` with `Mapper` somehow.  This lets you pass the object `a` only once to register it, and then you don't have to pass it for every call:

```
# mapper.py
Mapper = {'test': lambda a: Mapper['a'].foo}

# other module
from mapper import Mapper
Mapper['a'] = a
Mapper['test']()()
```

Note the two sets of parentheses at the end there: one set to evaluate the lambda and extract the function you want to call, and the second set to actually call that function.  You could do a similar deal by, instead of using `Mapper['a']` as the reference, using a module-level variable:

```
# mapper.py
Mapper = {'test': lambda: a.foo}

# other module
import mapper
Mapper = mapper.Mapper

mapper.a = a
Mapper['test']()()
```

Note that this requires you to do `import mapper` in order to set the module variable in that other module.

You could streamline this somewhat by using a custom class for `Mapper` instead of a regular dict, and having that class do some work in its `__getitem__` to look in a "known location" (e.g., read some module variable) to use as a base for evaluating `a`.  That would be a heavier-weight solution though.

The bottom line is that you simply cannot (again, without the use of `eval` or other such holes) write code in `mapper.py` that uses an undefined variable `a`, and then define a variable `a` in another module and have `mapper.py` automatically know about that.  There has to be some line of code somewhere that "tells" `mapper.py` what value of `a` you want it to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely follow, but `a` could "register" it's method with `Mapper` from anywhere which has a reference to Mapper:

```
#mapping.py
Mapper = {}
```

and then:

```
#main.py
from mapping import Mapper

#snip
a = A()
Mapper['test'] = a.foo #put your instance method into the Mapper dict.
#snip

Mapper['test']()
```

Comment: No sorry this is not what I want. The full definition of a function has to be given in `mapper.py` for any instance `a`. It is not known beforehand what `a` is. I will cleraify in the question.

Comment: @Alex: You can't expect a "full definition" if you don't know what the object is.  At some point you will have to specify what that object is.